# A non-numeric value encountered in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the quantity in text field and multiply it with the total price,but i always got the following error,can anyone help me in that?

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

```
<table class="table">
   <tr align="center">
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Product(S)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
   </tr>
   <?php 
       $total = 0;
       global $con; 
       $ip = getIp();
       $sel_price = "SELECT * FROM Cart WHERE IP_Address='$ip'";
       $pricerows = $con->query($sel_price)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       foreach ($con->query($sel_price) as $row_price) {
            $pro_id = $row_price['Product_ID'];
            $pro_price = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Product_ID='$pro_id'";
            foreach ($con->query($pro_price) as $row_proprice) {
                 $product_price = array($row_proprice['Price']);
                 $product_title = $row_proprice['Product_Name'];
                 $product_imaage = $row_proprice['Photo'];
                 $single_price = $row_proprice['Price']; 
                 $values = array_sum($product_price);
                 $total += $values;
    ?>  
 <tr align="center">
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"></td>
   <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br><img src="images/<?php echo $product_imaage; ?>" width="60" height="60"/></td>  
   <td><input type="text" size="4" id="qty" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>"/></td>
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {

    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $update_qty = "UPDATE cart set Quantity='$qty'";
    $updaterows = $con->prepare($update_qty);
    $updaterows->execute();

    $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;

    $total = $total*$qty;   //ERROR APPEARS HERE

 }
?>
<td><?php echo $single_price . " L.E";?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So where is `$total` assigned as and its value? and does `$_SESSION['qty']` have value?

Comment: btw; you will be updating your entire db without the use of a `WHERE` clause, unless that's what you want.

Comment: I asked for clarification on two counts and not getting any response. Take it up with the answer given then; I've left the question and a vote to close. You either logged off or waiting for a concrete answer. I for one cannot provide you with one, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the value to integer, you can use

```
int(your value) 

$total = $total* int($qty);
```

I hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: when i did that i got this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function int()`

Comment: Then use this 'intval($qty) ' without the quote

Comment: What you're trying to do is *casting*, by `(int)$qty`, which isn't exactly the same as doing `intval($qty)`

Answer (score 0):

Please don't insert unfiltered $_POST variables into sql queries, always use filters to prevent sql injections!

As far as I can see you're trying to multiply `$total` (which is not initialized) with `$qty` .

Please insert `$total = 0` (or an equal initialization) somewhere before this calculation!